# Can't delete group instance?

Tags: objects, groups

I have downloaded a Blender file, and the model is visible twice. 
I would like to have only 1 of them. But no matter what I try, I am unable to remove just one model.

I have uploaded the Blender file here: 
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38503

Could anybody tell me what is happening in this file? 
I think the maker of this file created a linked clone or so. 
Is this true?

Can anybody tell me how to have just 1 model?

Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object "chainsaw" is a [group instance](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/groups.html) of the group named "chainsaw" containing all the objects that make up the saw. You can delete it, or move all the objects that make up the group instance to another layer.

Answer (score 2):

Model which is called *Chainsaw* is a group instance. Select this model in Viewport or Outliner and click delete. You can add again this group by Shift+A => Group Instances => Chainsaw.

Answer (score 2):

You will notice that if you try to edit the one that turns green when you select it, the other model updates and these objects are on different layers. This is to allow making changes while transforming or animating the model elsewhere without the destructive side effects of working with one object.

Just simply grab the other model (the rotated one) which is a group instance of the original and press <kbd>X</kbd> to remove it. You could also create a new file and append (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>) the original model into that from the groups folder. Additionally, to get rid of the group (the green outline), go to the object tab and under groups delete it.